# F# Signature Understanding: "the -> operator and Compiler Errors"

Tags: compiler-errors, f#, signature

From time to time i get an error that looks like this:

```
opgave.fsx(28,14): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'int'
but here has type
    'int -> int'

opgave.fsx(33,35): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'int list'
but here has type
    'int -> int list -> int list'
```

What confuses me is what does it mean by the `->` operator? as i understand it then from the first error then it is expected an int but is given an expression that takes an int and returns another int. Perhaps i missunderstand ? If I am correct then what is the problem exactly? I could swear I have done something similar before.

the code these errors are based on looks like this:

```
member this.getPixelColors(x,y,p) : int list =
    let pixel = image.GetPixel(x,y)
    let stringPixel = pixel.ToString()
    let rec breakFinder (s:string) (h:int) =
      match s.[h] with
      |',' -> s.[9..(h-1)] |> int
      |_ -> (breakFinder(s (h+1))) // this is line 28
    let rec yello x y p =
      match x with
      |l when l = imageW -> match y with
                            |k when k = imageH -> p@[(breakFinder stringPixel 0)]
                            |_ -> yello((0)(y+1)(p@[(breakFinder stringPixel 0)])) // this is line 33
      |_ -> yello((x+1)(y)(p@[(breakFinder stringPixel 0)])) // there is an error in this line aswell identical to line 33
    yello 0 0 []
```

Can someone make me understand so i will be able to deal with this on my own in the future?

Comment: If you add the line numbers, or maybe put comments next to the lines that match up with the errors, that would help us identify the issues here.

Comment: I have added comments in the code. It is in every recursive call it errors

Comment: Thanks, that fits with my hypothesis. Please try my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When reading an F# function signature, the arrow (`->`) is a separator, and you can read the follow signature:

```
int -> int -> string
```

for example as a function that takes 2 `int`s and returns a `string`. One of the reasons it is presented like this is because you can also think of this function as a function that takes 1 `int` and returns you a function that takes 1 `int` and returns a `string`, this is called partial application.

In you case, I would use the line numbers in the error to help you pin point the issue.
So on line 28, you can given it a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`, but it wants an `int` value, maybe you forgot to invoke the function with an input?
On line 33, it wants `int list` which is another way of expressing `list<int>`. You however gave it a function that takes an `int`,  a `list<int>` and returns `list<int>`. Again, maybe you need to call this function with both inputs in order to satisfy your type constraint.

Edit: Looking again at this, I think I can guess which lines are the error ones. It looks like when you are invoking some of these funcions, you are putting multiple parameters in parentheses.
Try updating your code to this:

```
member this.getPixelColors(x,y,p) : int list =
    let pixel = image.GetPixel(x,y)
    let stringPixel = pixel.ToString()
    let rec breakFinder (s:string) (h:int) =
      match s.[h] with
      |',' -> s.[9..(h-1)] |> int
      |_ -> (breakFinder s (h+1))
    let rec yello x y p =
      match x with
      |l when l = imageW -> match y with
                            |k when k = imageH -> p@[(breakFinder stringPixel 0)]
                            |_ -> yello 0 (y+1) (p@[(breakFinder stringPixel 0)])
      |_ -> yello (x+1)(y)(p@[(breakFinder stringPixel 0)])
    yello 0 0 []
```

For example, to invoke `breakFinder` which has the signature `string -> int -> int`, you would do this: `let number = breakFinder "param1" 42`

Comment: This fixed it thanks! I see the problem now! You are the best!